# JS autocomplete for DBpedia

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dbpedia

For Freebase there is a very nice auto suggestion jquery plug-in, Freebase Suggest. It makes auto completion on specific entities (e.g. movie directors) and it will then only suggest those movie directors that are in Freebase. [Try here](http://code.google.com/p/freebase-suggest/)

Is there anything similar for DBpedia?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the virtuso built-in lookup service

http://dbpedia.org/fct/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a dbpedia lookup service

source code for a sample project here - https://github.com/pablomendes/dbpedia-spotlight-gsoc , demo here - http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/gsoc/ , details for dbpedia lookup here - http://dbpedia.org/lookup .

It's not quite as elegant as freebase suggest, but its not bad.

I would imagine that plenty of people would be interested in a open source sparql powered autocomplete ie. specify an endpoint and a base query.